# How can I get returned value from function in .jsf page adf 12c?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am calling a function on page load (.jsf page programmatically) and it's working fine, but function is returning (0 or 1) string value. I want to show or hide buttons based on returning value in jsf page.

How can I get returning value on .jsf page?

How can I apply logic of show and hide based on returning value?

Here is how I am calling function on page load

```
<f:metadata>
        <?audit suppress oracle.ide.xml.validation-error?>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{backingBeanScope.backing_login.viewPrivilidge('Program')}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Here is the code of  button on which i want to apply logic

```
 <af:button text="Supplier" id="b4" inlineStyle="width:190px;"
            destination="Supplier_Setup.jsf" icon="#{resource['images:supplier.png']}"/>
```

I am using .jsf page in adf 12c.

Comment: why are you using a "backing-bean" scoped bean?

Comment: Why does the function return 0 or 1 and not boolean? All users of this function will be able to write better code if it returns boolean. Having to test == "1" is brittle code and error-prone and contains unexpected complexities.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

only you need to call function in render attribute of that tag where you want to apply logic

```
<af:button text="Supplier" id="b4" inlineStyle="width:190px;"
            rendered="#{backingBeanScope.backing_login.viewPrivilidge('Program') == '1'}"           destination="Supplier_Setup.jsf" icon="#{resource['images:supplier.png']}"/>
```

"#{backingBeanScope.backing_login.viewPrivilidge('Program') == '1'}" .......... if your returning value is equal to '1' then it will render otherwise it will not render

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the use of Rendered. Rendered = false prevents any markup from being generated for that component. That means you can't simply set rendered = true on the component and expect it to appear - it won't. In this case you have to refresh a containing layout manager to get it to render. You probably want Visible=false here, then the markup is generated for the component and setting visible = true will make the component appear.

Rendered is often reserved for secure components where you do't want the markup in the page source at all.